# Who portrayed Ray Finkle in the file photo?

Tags: casting, ace-ventura-pet-detective

In Ace Ventura, Pet Detective, which actor portrayed Ray Finkle in the Miami Dolphins team photo of Finkle in his football uniform?

[image: Ray Finkle]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[According to the director](https://filmschoolrejects.com/36-things-we-learned-from-the-ace-ventura-pet-detective-commentary-c8c65ff518d2#.xfw7fnkma), the actor in the photograph is the same person that played Ray Finkle for the rest of the movie

> namely, actress Sean Young

merely costumed up to look more like a typical 70's football player.

To quote from the article:

> Ray Finkle in the team picture is played by Sean Young wearing a wig and fake mustache. Shadyac notes you can tell it’s Sean from the frail arms, but, from the neck up, she makes a very convincing man.